# ASP.NET Core cookie not working on the real host

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies, asp.net-core-mvc, host

I've created website with ASP.NET Core 7 MVC. I set my sign in user cookie in `program.cs` file for 24 hours as seen in this code:

```
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Home/Index";
    options.Cookie.Name = "WebAppIdentityCookie";
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
    options.LoginPath = "/Sign";
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});
```

The cookie worked correctly in debug mode, and it also worked correctly on publish for localhost on my Windows IIS. But when I put in on a real host, the cookie remains valid for only 5 minutes.

I try another value for days, minutes and etc. but nothing changes.

How can I fix this? Please help.

Comment: Is the production host's system clock set correctly? Are the values of `DateTime.UtcNow` identical in all 3 environments?

Comment: I do not know this. and how to check it?

Comment: i check it. i send ticket to my host provider and they fix it. (i think i have not access the clock of the server on my own.)